# Extract text between matched pattern and append text before the result

Tags: sed

I have a line of code like this  `"some_random_text_AP3_somerandomtext"`.

I'm trying to extract only this `AP3`. Since `AP` is fixed all the time, I used below solution.

```
echo "some_random_text_AP3_somerandomtext" | sed -n 's/.*AP\(.*\)_.*/\1/p'
```

It is successfully returning the number which is just `3`, so I used the below solution to append `AP` to it.

```
echo "some_random_text_AP3_somerandomtext" | sed -n 's/.*AP\(.*\)_.*/\1AP/p'
```

It is appending after `3` and the result is `3AP`, I actually want to append this before `3` like `AP3`, but not `3AP`.

Could someone point me out how to append it before?

Comment: The `.*` should be `[^_]*` to prevent greediness from affecting your result (if the random text after AP3 contains an underscore, for example).  That is not material to your current issue, though.

Comment: The replacement `'s/.*AP\(.*\)_.*/\1AP/p'` puts the `AP` after what was matched.  You presumably need `'s/.*AP\(.*\)_.*/AP\1/p'`.  And you should use `'s/.*AP\([^_]*\)_.*/AP\1/p'` for safety, as noted previously.

Comment: So you know that `\1` prints `3` and you know that `\1AP` prints `3AP` but you can't figure out what combination of `\1` and `AP` would print `AP3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer, as requested.*</sup>

The replacement `'s/.*AP\(.*\)_.*/\1AP/p'` puts the `AP` after what was matched (`\1`). You presumably need `'s/.*AP\(.*\)_.*/AP\1/p'`.

Also, the `.*` should be `[^_]*` to prevent greediness from affecting your result (if the random text after `AP3` contains an underscore, for example). So, for safety, you should probably use:

```
sed -n 's/.*AP\([^_]*\)_.*/AP\1/p'
```

Comment: `sed -n 's/.*\(AP[^_]*\)_.*/\1/p'` may also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `grep`:

```
echo "some_random_text_AP3_somerandomtext" | grep -Po 'AP[^_]*'         
AP3
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

**SEE ALSO:**
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: Thanks Timur shtatland, I might have used this but I have multiple operations on one line and I have ended up using sed for all of them, I appreciate for your answer though.